# How to tell if ANTLR4 parser consumed all tokens of the TokenStream?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have following ANTLR4 grammer definion. Note that rule "query" ends with optional subrule "orderLimit":

```
query: 'IDX.SELECT' indexName orderLimit?;
indexName: IDENTIFIER;
orderLimit: 'ORDERBY' order ('LIMIT' limit)?;
order: property;
property: IDENTIFIER;
limit: INT;
INT: '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z0-9_])*;
```

The generated parser accepts input text "IDX.SELECT orders LIMIT 30" without any error, with tokens "LIMIT 30" ignored silently.

However I want to detect and report such info so that users could amend their input to absolute correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor the `query` rule with the built-in `EOF` token:

```
query: 'IDX.SELECT' indexName orderLimit? EOF;
```

to force the parser to consume the entire token stream.